# Numerical solution of system of integral equations

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, integral-equations

I want to solve numerically a system of equations defined as

\begin{align}
\sum_{i,j} f_{ij}(r) &= 1 \\
0 &= A_{ijkl}f_{kl}(r) + \frac{1}{r^6}B_{ijkl}f_{kl}(r) \\
&+ f_{kl}(r)\left[\int_{r_0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r^4}f_{km}(r)\mathrm{d}r\frac{C_{kmon}}{\sqrt{f_{kk}(\infty)}}\right.\\
 &+ \left. \int_{r_0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{r^4}f_{lm}(r)\mathrm{d}r\frac{C_{lmon}}{\sqrt{f_{ll}(\infty)}}\right]
\end{align}

where the second equation holds for all $i,j,r$ and $A,B,C$ are known. My current numerical approach is to discretize over $r$, assume a starting set of $f_{ij}$ indep. of $r$, calculate the value between brackets and solve the resulting system for all $r$ to give a next guess for $f_{ij}$. This has a large radius of convergence but is too inaccurate.

What is the best numerical method/library for solving these types of equations, i.e. systems of equations involving integrals?

Answer (score 1):

Numerical methods for nonlinear system of equations are problem dependent and require lots of turning. Your approach is correct in theory, but there are lots of convergence issues. Maybe this is the reason why there is no general method/library.

There are some iteration methods in `Scipy`, which you can try and tune. It seems that to supply the Jacobian matrix is not essential in other direct or general methods, so maybe you can try them as well.

- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.nonlin.html

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I have tried out some of the optimize.root methods which require a lot of iterations to approximate the Jacobian; I also tried computing/inverting the Jacobian and it is very expensive.

Comment: Could you please show me how to implement this system in code? Preferably in Python, but any other language will do. I'm trying to write a solver with some iterative methods, but I don't really understand these equations :-) Will tell you if my approach works for this problem.

Comment: I started doing this, but realized that for a few reasons it would take a while to write a MWE and don't have time to do it currently. Still, thank you for the offer.